# How to run a script from Alfred or Spotlight or any run dialog?

Tags: macos, spotlight, script, command-line

Coming from Linux I am really missing the good old gmrun -- a run dialog
which recognizes your `$PATH` and allows you to execute any script in it
without needing to open up a terminal. It does the job and get out of the
way immediately.

I am wondering if I can make Alfred or spotlight do the same thing, or perhaps
find another tool?

#### Update 1

I have tried Dterm, but it keeps asking me for accessibility permissions, which I have already granted.

[image]

#### Update 2

- I have solved the above problem by going to privacy settings and check DTerm manually there:

[image]

- It's working right now, but not as smoothly as I would expect: the run dialog is still there after the command is issued, it would be much better if the window gets hidden.

[image]

Comment: You can close the Dterm window by a left click anywhere on your screen (as long it is outside the dterm window) or press shift-command-return or press `esc`. (press `command comma` for Dterm settings). As the Dterm website states: When you're done, hit escape or just go on about your work, and it'll automatically fade out, leaving your screen clutter-free.

Comment: A window screenshot is made by pressing `command shift 4`, release all, then tap `spacebar`, and then left-click to snap a photo.

Comment: And try not to change the original question as that will make all answers obsolete. If you have a new question, just create a new question instead of updating the previous one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Dterm

You might want to take a look at [Dterm](http://decimus.net/dterm). This is a dialog under <kbd>command</kbd><kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>return</kbd> and does exactly what you are looking for and it does even more than that.

As it says on the site:

"*DTerm provides a context-sensitive command line that makes it fast and easy to run commands on the files you're working with and then use the results of those commands.*"

[image: ping test Dterm]

Comment: It sounds great, but I am having trouble with granting permissions, please see my edit to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Type the command in DTerm, press enter, then press Esc. As @CousinCocaine suggested.